# PHP Change Turkish character to UTF8 Encoded Character

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to change Turkish character to  english character but it doesnt change.I want to
run query on mysql database.Mysql doesnt accept turkish character for query.So I couldnt run the query.

My SQL query is:

```
$sql_test="SELECT a.order_id as siparis_no,
           a.firstname as isim,
           a.lastname as soyisim,
           b.name as urun_Adi
           FROM zisl8_mijoshop_order a
           LEFT JOIN zisl8_mijoshop_order_product b
           ON a.order_id=b.order_id
           WHERE a.date_added>'$t_bas' and a.date_added < '$t_bit' AND b.name='Genel Bağış'
           ";
```

My PHP replace code:

```
$replace  = array('i', 's', 'o', 'c', 'g', 'u', 'I', 'G', 'O', 'C', 'S', 'U');
$search = array('ı', 'ş', 'ö', 'ç', 'ğ', 'ü', 'İ', 'Ğ', 'Ö', 'Ç', 'Ş', 'Ü');

$str='Genel Bağış';
$str=str_replace($search,$replace,$str);
```

I know there is no problem at PHP codes.But When try to show on page with echo :

string shows like this 'Genel Bağış'. So seem there is no change that I want make.

And MySQL query doesnt work.But When I change the string as manually like this:

```
$sql_test="SELECT a.order_id as siparis_no,
           a.firstname as isim,
           a.lastname as soyisim,
           b.name as urun_Adi
           FROM zisl8_mijoshop_order a
           LEFT JOIN zisl8_mijoshop_order_product b
           ON a.order_id=b.order_id
           WHERE a.date_added>'$t_bas' and a.date_added < '$t_bit' AND b.name='Genel Bagis'
           ";
```

Query is working.String of 'Genel Bağış' comes from mysql db.This is for illustrate  to my problem.

So where am I doing mistake, please help?

Answer (score 0):

In every PHP output header, specify UTF-8 as the encoding:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

**mysql_***

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
```

**mysql_* is deprecated**

**mysqli**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

**PDO**

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=mysql.example.com;dbname=example_db',
    "username",
    "password",
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

On the MySQL side of things, modifications to the `my.ini` file are required as follows:

```
[client]
default-character-set=UTF-8

[mysql]
default-character-set=UTF-8

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = false #force encoding to uft8
character-set-server=UTF-8
collation-server=UTF-8_general_ci

[mysqld_safe]
default-character-set=UTF-8
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting `utf8_encode`. It *cannot* possibly do anything useful here.

Comment: Ok. I couldnt tell the main problem .Sorry for that.My Main Problem transform 'Genel Bağış' to 'Genel Bagis'.There is no problem showing the characters.I want to run query with transformed string.I hope I can tell well the problem. Thanks

Comment: @tcetin I'd think your main problem is *"Mysql doesnt accept turkish character for query.So I couldn't run the query."* You should be solving that first and foremost.